# Optimising list creation in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, optimization

I am creating a list by using

```
sum_range=list(2**x for x in range(start_range,end_range+1))
```

Here the start_range and the end_range take large values from 0 to about 4 million.

This line of code seems to be the bottle neck. 
Ultimately I want the sum of all the number in the list sum_range. There can possibly be a better way to do this?

**Time take when:-**

start_range=188640 
end_range=197280

The code takes about 6 seconds to run on my system.

Comment: If you are using Python 2, use `xrange`, it uses lazy evaluation.

Comment: @idjaw: Considering how ridiculously huge `2**x` gets, NumPy wouldn't help.

Comment: You're trying to generate 2^4000000? Just running `2**(4 * 10**6)` alone is enough to freeze up my Python prompt for a good 30 seconds, are you sure this is something you need to do?

Comment: @idjaw I just tried using xrange, not much of optimisation. I think it has got to do with the large numbers.

Comment: Sum from 0 to n of 2**k is equal to 2**(n+1)-1.

Comment: @user2357112 Deleted that part of my comment. Was a naive comment based on a false understanding. Thanks for raising that to my attention.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko that looks great. I am trying it out

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Works marvelous! time down to milliseconds now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum over `2**n` is known algebraically. For n=0 to m it is : `2**(m+1)-1`.
So if you want to know it from a to b (inclusive)  take `2**(b+1) - 2**(a+1) + 2**a`.  Look up geometric series for the general case.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see Serge's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `"<<"` operator instead of `"**"`, it also will save computing time greatly from `4.0~5.0 seconds` to `0.07~0.33 seconds`.

```
import datetime

t_start_1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
sum_range_1 = list(1<<x for x in range(188640,197280))
t_end_1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print "using '<<' cost: " + str(t_end_1 - t_start_1) + "seconds"

t_start_2 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
sum_range_2 = list(2**x for x in range(188640,197280))
t_end_2 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print "using '**' cost: " + str(t_end_2 - t_start_2) + "seconds"
```

output:

```
using '<<' cost: 0:00:00.327000 seconds
using '**' cost: 0:00:04.990000 seconds
```

Comment: Great solution. I have combined both the formula and your solution. 1000 Iterations using formula used to take me 30 seconds. 1000 iterations using formula and << takes me 3 seconds.